# How to connect to the Ropsten test-net using web3.js

Tags: web3js, testnets, ropsten, infura

I want to connect to the **Ropsten** test-net:

```
    // Is there is an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fallback to the TestRPC.
      App.web3Provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
```

I have http://localhost:8545 in this code. How do I connect to Ropsten instead of http://localhost:8545?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either run a local node and specify your chain using `--chain ropsten` when starting geth/parity and connect to localhost once sync is completed or you can connect to `infura.io`:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/[infura_project_id]'
));
```

Comment: `geth --testnet --chain ropsten --rpc` Got this error: Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -chain

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad try omitting `--testnet`

Comment: `web3.eth.personal.currentProvider.connected = false` for me. Tried Infura ropsten, kovan and local ganache.

Answer (score 3):

You can also install metamask, which will inject web3 into the javascript runtime environment (assuming you are running this in the browser). From metamask, you can then select the chain/network as shown:

[image: Metamask dropdown]

Comment: For using this approach wee should run webpage on local server.

Answer (score 0):

To get infura links, please use : https://infura.io/